# Unable to resolve host name ping google.com ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dns, ping

I am getting error when using `ping google.com` saying could not resolve host address. I am using internet under a proxy server and i am getting my ip through dhcp dynamically and dns is set static. I could see in wireshark that tcp handshake syn between my computer and the dns server is sent but ack is received with reset flag set. Contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
```

Comment: what do you get in response to `dig +short www.google.com`?  How about if you edit `resolv.conf` to read `nameserver 8.8.8.8`?  Can you `ping 8.8.8.8` or `ping 208.67.222.222`?

Comment: yes i can ping both ip but when i use domain name it is giving error any command executed in terminal dig,nslookup etc are giving same error if i use host name

Comment: i changed the ip in resolv.conf to 8.8.8.8 but same error repeats

Comment: It appears your network or proxy may be blocking DNS requests' replies.

Comment: what is happening is whenever a syn packet is sent to 208.67.222.222 or 8.8.8.8 an ack packet is sent with reset flag set so the connection is reset but why is it resetting the connection that's the question

Comment: Does this happen when you do not route your connection through the proxy?  If not, your proxy may be to blame.

Comment: if my proxy is the issue is there any other way to do this i mean i want to bypass proxy restrictions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53137/discussion-between-jeevansai-jinne-and-dopeghoti).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're getting your IP via DHCP, have you tried using the DNS server that may have been provided via DHCP?  You probably need to point to an internal DNS server.  Suggest you talk to your networking team.

Comment: as far as i know 208.67.222.222 is the internal dns server ,how to find if there is any other dns server in the network

Comment: That IP and another you were given are external which would explain why your proxy might be disallowing:
% getent hosts 208.67.222.222   8.8.8.8
208.67.222.222  resolver1.opendns.com
8.8.8.8 google-public-dns-a.google.com

Best option is to ask your network team.  You could also cheat by looking at where your desktop resolves to--but I still reco you verify with your team.